# Finding the directional derivative of $f(x,y)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have this problem:

Let $f(x,y,z)=xyz$. Find the directional derivative in the direction of the velocity vector of the curve $\gamma(t)=(cos(3t),sin(3t),3t)$ on $t=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Is that the max. directional derivative of $f$ on that point?

How I can obtain the point where I have to consider the $\nabla f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear from the instructions that you will need the velocity vector for $\gamma$ at $t = \pi/3$, but implicit is that the point under consideration is the *position* vector for $\gamma$ at $t = \pi/3$. Calculate both of these, then use the gradient of $f$ to get your final answer.

Comment: Then, $\gamma (\frac{\pi}{3})=(-1,0,\pi)$ is the point where I need to take the gradient of f?

Comment: I really never would have guessed that.  "Expicit" is so much better than "implicit".

Comment: @Abrahamlure yep!

Comment: I understood that the curve $\gamma$ was given only to find the direction of the derivative, but not the point where I have to consider the gradient of $f$.